# Calling postgres function with JDBC from java doesn't work

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I created a function in postgresql, the function receives two varchar parameters and returns void, it works fine when I execute it in pgadmin, but I have problems trying to call it from java. I've tried calling the function using executeQuery and with some other examples I found. The problem is: in java it seems everything ok, but when I check the table in postgres there's no change on it, when the function is supposed to add a register.
I tried with this:

```
try (CallableStatement callableStatement = 
                dbConn.prepareCall("{ CALL prueba1(?,?) }")) {
            callableStatement.setString(1,mun);
            callableStatement.setString(2,edo);
            callableStatement.execute();
            callableStatement.close();
        }
```

And with this...

```
try (Connection conn = DBConnection.createConnection(); PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("{call prueba1(?,?)}")) {
        pstmt.setString(1,mun);
        pstmt.setString(2,edo);
        ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

But it's still not working... Any help would be great.

Comment: Could it be that the transaction is rolled back?

Comment: You're certainly getting an sql exception since executeQuery expects a ResultSet and your sql statement is an insert or update.

Comment: That looks like MySQL syntax, not PostgreSQL.

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński The `{call ... }` is a JDBC escape that hides database specific methods for executing stored procedures (functions), all JDBC drivers are required to implement it and translate it to the specific way for their database.

Comment: Note that there is no reason to use `callableStatement.close()` in your code: this is already called automatically by the try-with-resources.

Answer (score 0):

In your prepared statement try switching:

```
ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
```

With:

```
pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

Since your prepared statement actually returns void, there is no result set to return, and it is more effectively a directive like an insert or update - with no return value.

Comment: Thanks, i tried with this but i got the message "A result was returned when none was expected."
Also i changed the result of my plpgsql function to integer and returned "1" at the end of the function. In java i get the "1", but the rows in the table are still not added.